# Insert and Update Data Into Tables Linked by Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, rest

I am using Mysql

```
questions_set
==================
id | set_name

questions
==============================
id| set_id| question
```

set_id in questions table refer to question_set(id)
To insert a set for example
"set1"(set_name) add question "how are you" in questions table

```
1.get id from questions_Set table where set_name="set1"
2.if there is no id returned(there is no set1), insert set1
3.get id from questions_Set table where set_name="set1"
4.insert set_id and "how are you?" into questions table.
```

There are 4 SQL communication with database involved for this simple operation!!!

Is there any better way, which can be achievable using 1 SQL statement?

also i am postmapping this in db in spring boot.

Comment: *Is there any better way, which can be achievable using 1 SQL statement?* No. This can be compacted to 2 statements only. Steps 1-3 may be performed in one query `INSERT IGNORE`. Of course `set_name` must be defined as unique in table structure.

Comment: yes, set_name is set to unique. if you can explain the sql query it'll be helpful

Comment: If so simply `INSERT IGNORE INTO questions_set (set_name) VALUES ('set_1')`. If this name is present then the warning will be produced, not an error. And anycase after this the row with specified name is present in a table (of course except the case when an error occures during the insertion).